# ruby delete hidden characters from entire file

Tags: ruby

I have text file which contains the below hidden characters which I got with sed.

```
\033[H\033[2J\033
```

When I open file with vi and seeing the above code as below,

```
^[[H^[[2J^[[H^[[2J
```

Due to this hidden characters am facing some issue while processing file. Is there any to get rid of this hidden characters in entire file before processing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file size is not too big, you can read the whole file contents in, and then remove all the escaped sequences.

```
content = File.read('your_input_file_path')
content.gsub!(/\033\[(?:H|2J)/, '')
content.split(/\r?\n/).each do |line|
  # process line
end
```

You can generalize the Regex used according to the escaped sequence pattern. In you example, it seems it's `\033[` followed by an optional digit, and then a letter. Which can be updated as:

```
content.gsub!(/\033\[\d?[A-Z]/, '')
```

Comment: `content.gsub!(/\033\[\d?[A-Z]/, '')` is working perfect. Thank you!

Is there a best way if I want to remove all kind of hidden characters like above (not exact same above hidden characters).

Comment: @Karthick that really depends on your real case, I cannot give an answer here.

Comment: Thats Ok and I understood. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

One way to remove non-printing characters with ASCII values less than 32 (`" ".ord #=> 32`) follows.

```
def remove_invisible(infile, outfile)
  File.write(outfile,
    File.read(infile).
         codepoints.
         reject { |n| n < 32 }.
         map(&:chr).
         join
  )
```

Suppose `File.read(infile)` returns

```
str = "\033[H\033[2J\033"
  #=> "\e[H\e[2J\e"
```

then

```
a = str.codepoints
  #=> [27, 91, 72, 27, 91, 50, 74, 27] 
b = a.reject { |n| n < 32 }
  #=> [91, 72, 91, 50, 74] 
c = b.map(&:chr)
  #=> ["[", "H", "[", "2", "J"] 
c.join
  #=> "[H[2J"
```

Comment: How can I delete such below hidden characters as well?

^[[5m  
^[(B
^[[m
^M

At least if I can just delete ^ alone its fine.

Comment: I don't understand. `"^"` is not a hidden character.

Comment: yep sorry. it was carriage return